# Redux Saga calling same type multiple times simultaneously with different data

Tags: redux, redux-saga

Below is the flow of my app:

I have to fetch profile pics of creators of each posts in the list.

I have an action type `FETCH_USER_PROFILE`. The action contains `userId` to be passed to api call inside saga function.

Considering React application, the profile or Avatar component of the post dispatching the action based on the `createdByUserId` prop it receives from the parent post component.

I have a key in the reducer `isFetchingUserDetails`

whenever the action type `FETCH_USER_PROFILE` is dispatched, inside saga for it, I `yield-put isFetchingUserDetails` as `true`.

And when the response from api is received,I `yield-put isFetchingUserDetails` as `false`.

Based on `isFetchingUserDetails` I display the loader on Avatar component.

It works fine for one api call but when multiple dispatches of same action type is sent (with different `userIds` though) simultaneously, it modifies the `isFetchingUserDetails` continuously as api calls can take non-uniform time due to network constraints.

Due to this even for avatars or profile for which response is not fetched doesnot show loader because `isFetchingUserDetails` is set as true by the first response received.

Kindly suggest me what I can do in this scenario.

1. Should I make multiple action types with suffices as `userId`? Is this even possible?
2. Should I set `isFetchingUserDetails` suffixed with userId? But it would make multiple keys in reducers if the user count is `10k+`

Comment: One possible solution is to make your `isFetchingUserDetails` an integer - increment it at the beginning of the saga and decrement it at the end (preferably in a `finally` block so if there is an error the decrement still happens). Whenever `isFetchingUserDetails > 0` then show the loader.

You're going to have other issues if you have 10k users and are making a separate api call to load the user details for each but that's a separate discussion.

Comment: but suppose `isFetchingUserDetails = 10` for 10 posts at beginning of saga, then 1 saga gets completed, then `isFetchingUserDetails = 9` still it will show loader for all 10 posts, ideally only for 9 it should show loader

Comment: Oh, if you need to track each loader separately for each post, then yes, you'll need to have a separate piece of state for each loader, that's not avoidable. You could create a key in a Set() or an object and delete it after the loading is complete so the size of the state doesn't keep growing without bound.